# Logula Logging on Anonymous Class Instances

Tags: scala, logging, anonymous-class

Consider the following class definitions:

```
import com.codahale.logula.Logging
abstract class A extends Logging { log.info("from A") }
class C extends A { log.info("from C") }
```

They use [Logula](https://github.com/codahale/logula), a great logging library for Scala.

Creating an object of class `C` works great:

```
new C()
```

and produces the expected output:

```
INFO  [2012-03-31 19:16:14,261] C: from A
INFO  [2012-03-31 19:16:14,263] C: from C
```

But creating an instance of an anonymous sub-class of A

```
new A() {}
```

throws a `NullPointerException`:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.codahale.logula.Log$.clean(Log.scala:25)
    at com.codahale.logula.Log$.forName(Log.scala:23)
    at com.codahale.logula.Log$.forClass(Log.scala:18)
    at com.codahale.logula.Logging$class.log(Logging.scala:172)
    at A.log(LoggingTraitTest.scala:3)
    at A.<init>(LoggingTraitTest.scala:3)
    at LoggingTraitTest$$anon$1.<init>(LoggingTraitTest.scala:8)
    at LoggingTraitTest$delayedInit$body.apply(LoggingTraitTest.scala:8)
    at scala.Function0$class.apply$mcV$sp(Function0.scala:34)
    at scala.runtime.AbstractFunction0.apply$mcV$sp(AbstractFunction0.scala:12)
    at scala.App$$anonfun$main$1.apply(App.scala:60)
    at scala.App$$anonfun$main$1.apply(App.scala:60)
    at scala.collection.LinearSeqOptimized$class.foreach(LinearSeqOptimized.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:45)
    at scala.collection.generic.TraversableForwarder$class.foreach(TraversableForwarder.scala:30)
    at scala.App$class.main(App.scala:60)
    at LoggingTraitTest$.main(LoggingTraitTest.scala:6)
    at LoggingTraitTest.main(LoggingTraitTest.scala)
```

A similar exception is thrown if an anonymous sub-class of `C` is instantiated: `new C() {}`

Why is there any difference between an explicit and an anonymous class instantiation here?

Any hint about how I could find out what is happening would be welcome. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that Logula wants a canonical name for the class, which doesn't exist for anonymous classes. See for example the documentation for [`Class.getCanonicalName`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getCanonicalName%28%29):

> Returns the canonical name of the the underlying class as defined by
>   the Java Language Specification. Returns null if the underlying class
>   does not have a canonical name (i.e., if it is a local or anonymous
>   class or an array whose component type does not have a canonical
>   name).

So it looks like you're out of luck on this one, but if you really, really needed to be able to use logging with anonymous classes, you could replace `getCanonicalName` with `getSimpleName` in the following line (18) of [`Log.scala`](https://github.com/codahale/logula/blob/37395e70ddcad25360877be97f7fe48f81f0d06d/src/main/scala/com/codahale/logula/Log.scala) in the Logula source:

```
def forClass(klass: Class[_]) = forName(klass.getCanonicalName)
```

This gives me the following output:

```
0    [main] INFO  C  - from A
1    [main] INFO  C  - from C
1    [main] INFO  anon.2  - from A
2    [main] INFO  anon.1  - from A
2    [main] INFO  anon.1  - from C
```

Which is more or less what you want, probably. I'm not familiar enough with Logula to know whether this change would introduce headaches down the line, though.

Comment: I also found that it is easy to create you're own logula logger: `lazy override val log = Log.forClass(classOf[A])` in class `A` will make all anonymous instances of `A` uses `A`'s class as a logger resolution name.